Some details missing on an exercise on analytic continuation
An exercise in Conway about an analytic continuation of the square root
A comment under the top answer points  out that as it is currently written the answer is wrong: the condition that implies that the $2$ functions coincide in the intersection of the rispective domain is too loose and i am trying to fix that. Intuitively i think taking $ \lvert s - t \rvert < 1/2$ should be enough but i can't spot the mistake in the original answer.
